# The mean value of sample moment with order k

Tags: statistics, means, sampling

I've this problem of statistics that I can't resolve. So I hope that someone can halp me.

The problem is this:

Let sampling moments $\overline{X_n^k}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^k$, where for $k=1$  $\overline{X_n^k}=\overline{X_n}$.

Show that $E(\overline{X_n^k})=E(X)$, where $E(Y)$ is the mean value of $Y$.

I did this:

$E(\overline{X_n^k})=E(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^k)=\frac{1}{n}E(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^k)$

I think that for ID of $X_i$, I can write:

$\frac{1}{n}E(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^k)=\frac{1}{n}*nE(X_i^k)=E(X_i^k)$.

Is this correct? And how can I go on? I thought to use the moment generating functions, but I don't know use it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, $E(\overline{X^k})=E(X)$ certainly doesn't hold *in general*. This, if at all,  can only be true for particular value distributions, so we need more information on those.

Comment: Did you intend to say "Show that $E\left(\overline{X_n^k}\right)=E\left(X^k\right)$" with a $\,^k$ on the right hand side?

Comment: I think that $X_i$  have random variable generative $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma ^2)$. My teacher didn't specify it, for this reason I didn't write it. But before of this exercise we treated this random variable.

Comment: I don't know Henry. This is the text that my teacher gave us, but she may have been wrong.